# How to create a function to that returns next line of input in C

Tags: c, fgets, c-strings, calloc

I'm pretty new to C, so as part of my learning I want to make a function that simply returns a string which is the next line in the input without any arguments needed.

This is what I have so far:

```
#define BUFFER 256
char *str;
char *getline()
{
    if (str == 0)
        str = (char*)calloc(BUFFER, sizeof(char));
    if (fgets(str, BUFFER, stdin) != 0)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        if (len > 0 && str[len-1] == '\n')
            str[len-1] = '\0';
        return str;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, is this the best way to do such thing? Is there a better way you can thing of?
If it is the best way, where should I free what I've allocated with `calloc`?

Comment: Who is responsible for freeing `str`? what if the line is longer than 256? There is no way to do it without parameters in a secure way.

Comment: oh, and `str` should be either local or an array.

Comment: @H2CO3 are you comfortable with this interface for getline - `str == 0`? it is a singleton-object-with-public-fields in disguise.

Comment: @Elazar I don't understand what you mean by that...

Comment: @H2CO3 but you did fix your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but here are some notes to keep in mind:

- [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
- You don't even need `calloc()` - `fgets()` NUL-terminates the string.
- Even better, use a `static` array.
- Don't use global variables. Declare `str` with `static` storage duration instead.
- Instead of 256, use `LINE_MAX` - how come a line can only be shorter than 256 characters?
- `getline()` is the name of a function in the POSIX C library. Rename your function to avoid name collision.
- **Check if `malloc()` failed!**
- Don't forget to `free()` the return value of the function after having read the last line if you use the approach with dynamic memory management.
- The check for the newline ending can be simplified like this:

---

```
char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
if (p)
    *p = 0;
```

All in all, the function I would write is something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

char *my_getline_stdin()
{
    static char buf[LINE_MAX];

    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
        char *p = strchr(buf, '\n');
        if (p)
            *p = 0;

        return buf;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```